# Sharepoint: Add record to List 1 and link new records in List 2 to List 1

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps

I have two Sharepoint lists: `Customers`(Parent) & `Invoices`(Child). The Customers table contains customer info: (ID, Name, CustNum, Currency, Notes). The Invoices table contains invoice info: (invoice, invoice amt, invoice date, etc.).

Now my goal is to have a 1-to-many relationship where I use the system generated ID to link Customers to Invoices. It's possible a customer will appear multiple times in the Customer table, so we want to link the tables using the ID as opposed to the Customer Number. The reason being we are tracking unpaid invoices and customers might have multiple instances of outstanding balances.

I have two forms. The first the use enters the customer info then they submit the info to the customer list and it navigates them to the Invoice detail screen. Here they can add an invoice and submit, or submit and add another invoice by filling out the form again for each invoice they have. The concept here is that they'll have a customer with potentially multiple invoices when they're filling out the form and we want to have each iteration of the invoice addition to pull in that ID from the Parent list(Customers) and add it to the new record in the Invoices list.

**Problem 1**:
We are able to add data to both lists using the forms; however, the child list, `Invoices`, doesn't link to the `ID` we just created from the parent table automatically, even though we setup a lookup. **How can we have the ParentID pull into the Child List as the user adds invoices?**

Answer (score 0):

Are u using patch or submitform for saving your forms?
I suggest that you create a global variable with your customer record...
And set that global variable as you work in your app...
After onsucces on submitform
Set(gblCustomer, YourForm.LastSubmit)
Or select customer from gallery
Set(gblCustomer, galCustomers.Selected)
And now you can set a default vslue in your childform
Unlock the customerId field,
And set the default as:
GblCustomer.CustomerId

I hope you get it figured out!
Greetz,
W

Comment: Hi, I'm using submitform to save the form. Regarding the LastSubmit, if the user is entering a series of invoices into the child list, will the lastsubmit update to the most recent invoice over the new customer?

Comment: You use 2 forms, 1 customer, 1 child invoice... gblCustomer on customer.lastsubmit, newform(child invoice) and here s the relational trick: unlock invoice customerId field and set default to gblCustomer.id